Nuxt-Swiper add css style tags + link (render blocking css, same css as style tags) in head at build time, How to stop render blocking?
I'm building a Nuxt 3 monorepo application and using the nuxt-swiper module for horizontal scrolling functionality. However, the module injects the swiper.css file as a render-blocking resource, impacting initial page load performance.
Problem:
The nuxt-swiper module is adding the css style tags in head at the time of build.
At the same time it also adds the link of external css style which is render blocking.
The external css file css rules and stype tags css rules are same.
I want to remove the render blocking css file
Image 1
Image 2
Desired Behavior:
swiper css should be inline css only, no external css link.
or external css should be non-render blocking.
tried possible ways:
1st - lazy load swiper CSS - add CSS in the head only when myCourses component is rendered, it shifted the swiper CSS loading network call from 3rd to 7th or 8th place but CSS is still render-blocking
2nd - remove swiper CSS from build just like we are do for entry.css
this solution is not working for Swiper CSS
https://deltener.com/blog/stop-render-blocking-css-in-nuxt/
3rd - someone else also faced the same issue on GitHub, but issue is still open
https://github.com/cpreston321/nuxt-swiper/issues/116
4th - currently trying this solution
https://github.com/cpreston321/nuxt-swiper/issues/84
Will update, if I will found a solution
